# Why is there hell when Allah loves humans?

Tags: punishment, jahannam, love

Whenever I see sufferings, pain, hunger, sorrow, tests and when I feel these, it makes me wonder if Allah loves humans, then why did he have to create earth and test people, and why does he put people into hell when he says he loves more than mother. How can he do this?

Answer (score -1):

**I wish you ponder the same about eternal paradise.**

### Why are we on planet earth?

**Can't Allah just send you directly to Paradise or hellfire? Does he need to test your deeds first?**

Your existence in this life is a testimony for YOU, and an established proof against YOU, not Allah.
Acceptance or rejection of Allah, is to be of full consciousness, so you live to see.

> This, Our record, speaks about you in truth. Indeed, We were having
>   transcribed whatever you used to do. 45-29

And this would suggest that you are even given a chance to discuss and dispute for what you have done!

> On the Day when every soul will come disputing for itself, and every
>   soul will be fully compensated for what it did, and they will not be
>   wronged. 16-111

**What about suffering and sorrow we witness?**

Allah is the source of every goodness

> And whatever you have of favor - it is from Allah . Then when
>   adversity touches you, to Him you cry for help. 16-53

Amazingly Allah tells you about the source of pain you may find in this life as well..

> What comes to you of good is from Allah, but what comes to you of
>   evil, [O man], is from yourself. And We have sent you, [O Muhammad],
>   to the people as a messenger, and sufficient is Allah as Witness. 4-79

So, suffering we witness is related to disobedience of Allah!
Now, I will ask you something: If a man killed 3 people, how many times, at most can you kill him ? apparently even if you punish him with death, still there are the rights of the families and children of his victims.. and many more things that are a result of his action.. so if Allah is just , and He is, He has definitely to punish that person.

Trusting the Allah, the Al Just, is what you need to do. even despite the fact He can just punish, He is allowing people to dispute, even though their deeds are recorded, do you think He might be oppressing them?

Again:

> On the Day when every soul will come disputing for itself, and every
>   soul will be fully compensated for what it did, and they will not be
>   wronged. 16-111

All would be paid in full, and none will be wronged.

> And We place the scales of justice for the Day of Resurrection, so no
>   soul will be treated unjustly at all. And if there is [even] the
>   weight of a mustard seed, We will bring it forth. And sufficient are
>   We as accountant. 21-47

Allah's Mercy is everywhere, but corruption and disbelief is what causes this sadness. Trust Allah, as He is the Al merciful, the Al Just.